# Is it possible in a Sharepoint 2010 workflow to annote a field whose content has been updated?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

To add to the rest of the question onto the the above " by changing it to a different color or adding a label of UPDATED or EDITED next to it?"

Comment: You can add the text but you can't change the color, not without JavaScript or some other code.  What tool are you using to make the workflow?

Comment: I don't understand. So we can't mark a field when it has been updated? It doesn't matter if the old content shows I just need the recipient of the form via email to know just by looking what has been changed. Which is a similiar function to what Alerts do in Sharepoint 2010. Sharepoint 2013 which is what I am using with a 2010 workflow doesn't allow what the Alerts did to task updates in Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: @Robbert I am using Sharepoint Designer 2013 with a 2010 Workflow. Color doesn't matter just to be able to label the fields that changed when the recipient receives the email.

Comment: Only way I can think of doing this is to set enable versioning on the list and then use code to check the values of the fields between the current and previous version. If they are different, change the color or do whatever. Either way, you have to use either the client or server object model to accomplish this.

Comment: @Robbert which is something I don't know how to do, is there an example of this written up for the client or server object model to accomplish this? I am not familiar with ASP if that is what I am going to have to write up

Comment: Look into jQuery and SPServices.  There's lots of code on the internet to at least show you how to retrieve list items and display them on the screen.